# ValueError at /music/4/favorite/ invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: django, exception, django-forms

Here I am getting the  ValueError at /music/4/favorite/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

```
    Request Method: POST
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/4/favorite/
    Django Version: 1.10.5
    Exception Type: ValueError
    Exception Value:    
    invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
    Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-            packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 946
    Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
    Python Version: 2.7.12
    Python Path:    
    ['/home/user/python/official-django-tutorial/MusicApp',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
     Server time:   Tue, 24 Jan 2017 15:13:57 +0530
```

Here is the view.py for the project

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
    from .models import Album,Song

    def index(request):
      all_albums=Album.objects.all()
      context={"all_albums":all_albums}
      return render(request,'Music/index.html',context)

   def detail(request,album_id):
      album=get_object_or_404(Album,pk=album_id)
      return render(request,'Music/detail.html',{"album":album})

   def favorite(request,album_id):
      album=get_object_or_404(Album,pk=album_id)
      try:
        selected_song=album.song_set.get(pk=request.POST['song'])
      except(KeyError,Song.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request,'Music/detail.html',{"album":album,"error_message":"You Did Not Selected a valid Message"})
   else:
      selected_song.is_favorite=True
      selected_song.save()
      return render(request,'Music/detail.html',{"album":album,})
```

here is the detail template for this one,

```
    <img src="{{ album.album_logo}}">
    <h1>{{ album.album_title }} </h1>
    <h3>{{ album.artist }}
    <h4>Here are the Available Songs</h4>

    {% if error_message %}
      <p>{{error_message}}</p>
    {% endif%}  

    <form action="{% url 'Music:favorite' album.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for song in album.song_set.all %}
      <input type="radio" id="song{{ forloop.counter }}" name="song" value="{{ songs.id }}">
      {{song.song_title}}
      <!label for="{{forloop.couter}}"{{song.song_title}}></label>
      {% if song.is_favorite %}
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/b9b13Rd.png">
      {% endif %}
      <br>

    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Favorite">
    </form>
```

how can I solve this problem? Thank u

Comment: It looks like your code is not handling the case when `request.POST['song']` is an empty string `''`.

Comment: empty string? why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is using `{{ songs.id }}`. It should be `{{ song.id }}`.

```
<input type="radio" id="song{{ forloop.counter }}" name="song" value="{{ song.id }}">
```

Rendering your own inputs is error-prone, like in this case. If you use [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/) it decreases the chance of mistakes.

Comment: thanks bro u saved my day :) also why I am not getting errors that shows this variable

Comment: There isn't a `songs` variable in your context, so Django [uses an empty string by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#how-invalid-variables-are-handled). If you looked at the rendered html then you might have spotted the problem.